# jQuery height of element.style

Tags: jquery, css

How do I get height of DIV, that is set by jQuery?
`$('.bar2').animate({'height':'58' + "%"},1500);`

When I inspect elements in chrome I see that my DIV height is set to 58%

`<div class="bar2" style="height: 58%; background-image: ......>`

I have tried this:

`var bar2 = $(".bar2").height(),` or `var bar2 = $(".bar2").css('height'),`

but I always get my "min-height" which is 70px, not height that is set by jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: blue;">
    <div class="bar2" style="min-height: 70px; width: 100px; background-color: red;">foo</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('.bar2').animate({'height':'58' + "%"}, 1500, function() {
    alert($(".bar2").css('height'))
});
```

Live example here - http://jsfiddle.net/ANbrq/1/

You can only get a different height when it's actually changed. If you're trying to get it right after you ask it to resize, you'll get the initial height.

Answer (score 3):

I think you would use:

```
$(".bar2").outerHeight();
```

Which is the computed height or

```
$(".bar2").innerHeight();
```

If you don't need to take account margin and padding and what-not.

Comment: `$.outerHeight()` will include the element's borders and padding in the returned value. Your answer [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/BTcfe/), unfortunately.

Comment: In your example the height will be 50 pixels as it has nothing to be 58% off so the min-height will take affect.

Comment: I take my comment back; [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/BTcfe/1/) works, having set a height on `<body>`.